# Issue trying to output WordPress post data with Vue

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js

Can anyone tell me why I am getting an error when trying to output the post data?

I've tried adding params like title, content but nothing works. I might add that I can get it to work using the id.

```
    <template>
      <section class="container animated fadeIn">
        <nuxt-link :to="{ name: 'blog' }">
          Back to Blog
        </nuxt-link>
        <div>
          <h1 class="title">
             {{ post }}  <!-- this returns an array of the post data  -->
              {{ slug }} <!-- this returns the slug  -->
                {{ post.title }} <!-- this returns an error  _vm.post is undefined  -->
          </h1>
        </div>
      </section>
    </template>
    <script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
      name: 'post',
      data () {
        return {
          slug: this.$route.params.slug,
          post: {},
          error: []
        }
      },
      asyncData ({ params }) {
        return axios.get(`http://localhost/amcdwp/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?slug=${params.slug}`)
          .then((response) => {
            return { post: response.data }
          })
      }
    }
    </script>
```

I want to output individual data like post.title. I get an error of _vm.post is undefined

Comment: If `{{ post }}` returns an array as you indicate, wouldn't you need to access a specific index, eg `{{ post[0].title }}`?

Comment: hello, yes that works, thanks for that however how do I get in meta:meta: [{ hid: 'description', id: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'say if I want post title here' }]

Comment: Thank you for this I got it worked, pretty silly but I was trying to loop out, you put me on the right track